# Is it possible to make two I/O intensive processes run concurrently/parallely in python gui?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

My goal is to show the progress of `pyinstaller` while it is creating an exe file in my Customtkinter based application. I have created a `customtkinter.TCkToplevel` class to display the progress, but my attempts to use the threading library have failed. Here is my code:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import threading
import subprocess

_exe_creation_done = False 

class CreateExe(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__int__()
        self.geometry('400x600')
        self.btn = ctk.CTkButton(master=self, text='Start', command=self.start_processes)
        
    def start_processes(self):
        self.top_level = ProcessRunning()
        background_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.create_application_exe)
        foreground_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.top_level.increment_x_pos())
        background_thread.start()
        foreground_thread.start()
        
        background_thread.join()
        foreground_thread.join()
    
    def create_application_exe(self):
        global _exe_creation_done
        try:
            subprocess.run(['pyinstaller', '--onefile', '--noconfirm', 'script.py'], shell=True)
        except:
            pass
        _exe_creation_done = True

class ProcessRunning(ctk.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry('200x300')
        
        self.label_x_pos = 0.03
        
        self.rect_label =  ctk.CTkLabel(master=self, text='', fg_color='darkgreen')
        self.rect_label.place(relx=self.label_x_pos, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.1)
        
        self.progress_text = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self, text='EXE CREATION IN PROGRESS ...', font=ctk.CTkFont(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight='bold'))
        self.progress_text.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.6)
    
    def increment_x_pos(self):
        max_x_pos = 1.03
        min_x_pos = -0.03
        increment = 0.08
        while True:
            self.label_x_pos += increment
            self.rect_label.place_forget()
            self.rect_label.place(relx=self.label_x_pos)
            self.label_x_pos = min_x_pos if self.label_x_pos > max_x_pos else self.label_x_pos
            if _exe_creation_done:
                break
        
        self.progress_text.configure(text="DONE!")
        self.destroy()
```

Assume the exe creation method works smoothly even if the above method got some typos.

The outcome is neither toplevel window created nor exe produced.
I guess the problem could be threading **deadlock??** since the two processes are both I/O intensive. How can I overcome this issue?